# How to draw as many objects as the value of your data with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to make a chart wherein a person, the image, represents 100.000 people. In my json-file is all the information located of the population of all cities in the netherlands. For the simplicity I only took two cities. Amsterdam, for example, should show six people. Placing a simple for-loop around the bars.append statement won't work. What is he best solution in this case?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var data= [{"Amsterdam": {"Population":"800000"},
                "Utrecht": {"Population":"600000"}}]

    var vis = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", 2000)
        .attr("height", 2000)
        .append("svg:g");

    var bars = vis.selectAll("g.bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("svg:g");

    bars.append("svg:image")
        .attr("xlink:href", "http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/communpedia/images/0/0f/Person.png/revision/latest?cb=20110525230905")
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("height", 100)
        .attr("x", 50)
        .attr("y",50);  
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: how should it show the people? stacked on top of each other ? next to each other?

Comment: You probably want [`d3.range()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_range), but drawing hundreds of thousands of individual symbols won't work.

Comment: @Alex_B I would prefer next to eachother